# Bitbucket default repository not configured

Tags: c#, git, mercurial, bitbucket

I am totally lost here as i have been trying to create a repository and push my existing Unity3D C# project to it.

The current output is:

```
realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
user: 
password: 
warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint 46:de:34:e7:9b:18:cd:7f:ae:fd:8b:e3:bc:f4:1a:5e:38:d7:ac:24 not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint 46:de:34:e7:9b:18:cd:7f:ae:fd:8b:e3:bc:f4:1a:5e:38:d7:ac:24 not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting) 
searching for changes
warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint 46:de:34:e7:9b:18:cd:7f:ae:fd:8b:e3:bc:f4:1a:5e:38:d7:ac:24 not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint 46:de:34:e7:9b:18:cd:7f:ae:fd:8b:e3:bc:f4:1a:5e:38:d7:ac:24 not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
abort: error: ''
Peters-iMac:myProject Peter$ hp puch -v --debug
-bash: hp: command not found
Peters-iMac:myProject Peter$ hg push -v --debug
pushing to default-push
abort: default repository not configured!
(see the "path" section in "hg help config")
Peters-iMac:myProject Peter$
```

I have been trying to understand what i need to do to fix this but have not succeeded, i did check the "hg help config" but did not fully understand anyhow.

Anyone that can lead the blind (me)?

Comment: Probably worth noting that BitBucket is currently having [lots of issues](http://status.bitbucket.org/) so this might not be your fault.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell mercurial where to push to. You can do that in two ways:

1. Command line: `hg push URL` where URL is the pathwhere to push to, e.g. `hg push https://bitbucket.org/YOURLOGIN/YOURREPOSITORY` (it then will ask for login and pw on the command line)
2. In your repository's configuration file found in .hg/hgrc:

   [paths]
   default = https://bitbucket.org/YOURLOGIN/YOURREPOSITORY

See also `hg help config.paths`

You can also use the hgrc to store the login information in order to remove the need to enter them each time you push, but that is unsecure. Better use ssh authentication which doesn't require storing any credentials.

Comment: Please use proper Markdown list markup, as I did in my edit.